# C# coding standards for private member variables

Tags: c#, coding-style

I saw two common approaches for coding standards for private member variables:

```
class Foo
{
    private int _i;
    private string _id;     
}
```

and

```
class Foo
{
    private int m_i;
    private string m_id; 
}
```

I believe the latter is coming from C++. Also, many people specify type before the member variable (e.g. `double m_dVal`) to indicate that it is a non-constant member variable of the type double?

What are the conventions in C#?

Comment: @Andrew Hare  NOT exact duplicate as I am asking for a general case and not just m_. thx for pointing out the link though...

Comment: That "dupe" was closed as S&A. This question is valid (and driis' answer was very helpful, I might add).

Answer (score 69):

Besides the two you mention, it is very common in C# to not have a prefix for private members.

```
class Foo
{
    private int i;
    private string id; 
}
```

That is what I use, and also what is recommended in [Microsoft's internal naming guidelines](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/articles/361363.aspx).

See also these [.NET naming guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines).

Comment: Agreed, with the one exception that personally I will prepend a _ character when the private member is the backing store for a public property.

Comment: I prefer the underscore because I like knowing the scope of the variable just by looking at the name

Comment: I also always use an underscore prefix for property backing fields, as its easy to make a mistake and get a... stackoverflow hur ;)

Comment: At least in Java you can let the compiler complain about member accesses without the "this." qualifier. I prefer "this.x" over "_x" (which is still ambigous).

Comment: @Marcel you can use `this.` in C# too. Makes the `_` 'fudge' redundant if you ask me...

Comment: "i" should never be used as a variable.  Neither should a, b, c, d, ...  i could mean imaginary or integer, which is ambiguous.  Always spell out your names meaningful and never use abbreviations!  The only place where abbreviations help is in non-compiled scripting languages (javascript, perl, bash, php, and SQL, for example).  Id is pretty standard, but be sure to tag <CLSComplient> _ or [CLSComplient] in front of your class. Since this won't flag any errors for private fields, your free to do whatever.  Always pick a standard everyone on the project agrees. Set it before starting/joining.

Comment: `i` should never be used as a property or field name. It is, however, standard practice to use a variable named `i` to iterate a for loop (and even `j` for a nested loop). The only time I _wouldn't_ do this is when iterating through a 2D/3D grid, in which case I would use `x`, `y`, `z`.

Comment: Class "Foo", but next meta var is "i"? Your example style is bad like your answer.

Comment: I like the underscore prefix because it keeps autocomplete from changing my properties into stackoverflows...

Comment: The Microsoft guidelines you referenced are now incredibly old, and no longer apply. Internal and private fields are now specifically excluded from Microsoft's naming guidelines as stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-type-members#names-of-fields).

Comment: @Neo Yes, the answer is almost 10 years old ;) But nevertheless I think that the _suggestion_ to not use a prefix is still sound, even if MS doesn't include it in their naming guidelines.

Comment: @driis Why?....

Comment: The link is now broken. Archive.org copy: https://web.archive.org/web/20100316191542/http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/articles/361363.aspx

Answer (score 15):

As noted by [Brad Abrams: internal coding guidelines](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/articles/361363.aspx):

> Do not use a prefix for member
>   variables (`_`, `m_`, `s_`, etc.). If you
>   want to distinguish between local and
>   member variables you should use
>   “`this.`” in C# and “`Me.`” in VB.NET.

Comment: @Konrad Radolph: Seems like they have an implicit *internal* guideline: don't use VB :)

Comment: I imagine that they must.  I wish I had a link, but I read a recommendation that case not be used as the only distinguishing factor in C# to maintain interopt compatibility.

Comment: @Steve Brouillard: Yes. That's for *public* members, though. You shouldn't have two public members that are different only in case. It's not CLS compliant.

Comment: +1 to @Steve for noting this applies to public members and CLS compliance.  Private members have a lot more freedom. C# or VB.net.  Nothing else should directly access them. But be sure to be consistent throughout the project.  And always code for the next person to take over.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Using case as the sole distinction between class members is a horrible practice, regardless of whether the language supports it.

Answer (score 15):

I think the important principle here is that you're consistent. Use a "_" or "m" prefix if that's what you like to do and it's consistent with the rest of the code you're working with. Whatever you choose, stick with it and be consistent.

Comment: amen. Consistency shall be the only standard that's required.

Answer (score 11):

I prefer to use your first example, or auto-properties like this, which avoid having the private fields defined in your class at all:

```
public String MyString { get; set; }
```

Use the `prop` snippet to make these REALLY fast.

Comment: Works except that you cant make auto properties read-only... ah well, maybe I'll look for it in C# 5.0.

Comment: You can make them "read-only" by making the set private or protected: public String MyString { get; private set; }

Comment: Except that then they're not precisely read-only, a class method can still reset it.

Comment: A class method could also set a private field ... what's the difference?

Comment: I guess @Michael meant read-only in the sense of being directly unmodifiable outside the class and not the keyword readonly. Overloading of English words at work here. :)

Comment: Yes, I meant this: private readonly string foo;public String MyString { get { return foo; } }

Answer (score 8):

As I recall from reading [Framework Design Guidelines](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321545613), there really is no set convention for private member variables, except that one should not use Hungarian notation and one should not capitalize the first letter of the variable name (use Camel-casing).  There are quotes in the book that support both of your examples, as well as not using any prefix at all.

Personally, I prefer the "m_" prefix.

Answer (score 7):

General guidance from Microsoft here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx

Automatic properties in C# are great and I uses then when I can but there are cases where they don't work for me such as when doing type or value checking on a set method.

In general: use camel casing and don't prefix your name with anything such as underscore or a type prefix.

```
public int Age {get; set;}
```

or

```
private int age;
public int Age
{
    get { return age; }
    set
    {
        if(value < 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Age > 0");
        age = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not a fan of throwing exceptions is property getter/setters. But that's a different can of worms :)

Comment: I agree and not something that I even infrequently do. More for illustration. Agreeed, a different can o-worms.

Comment: Just a note, this document says "The field-naming guidelines apply to static public and protected fields. Internal and private fields are not covered by guidelines, and public or protected instance fields are not allowed by the member design guidelines." So, no official guidance.

Answer (score 6):

Best is to use whatever is already used in the project. If you start a new project, use whatever is most often used in the company.

Comment: If you start a new company, throw a coin. :)

Answer (score 5):

I prefer underscore as prefix for private non const non readonly fields. Why? Reasons:
1. Simply looking on variable I can distinguish between field & local/parameter variable. Using "this." for all fields is not an option - its longer.
2. There is ambiguity between parameter and field:

```
class Foo
{
  private int id;
  public Foo(int id)
  {
    id = id; //Will compile and work fine. But field will not be initialized.
  }
}
```

Comment: This specific scenario will generate a warning though.

Comment: @MatthijsWessels How many places enforce a 0 warning in builds policy ?

Comment: @Noctis you'll see a squiggly line though in most editors. So you'll get that visual cue.

Answer (score 5):

I personally have always used your first example of:

```
    public class Foo
    {
        private int _i;
        private string _id;
    }
```

In fact, that's what my entire team uses.  Additionally the one you mentioned `m_dVal` is known as Hungarian Notation, here is the [Wikipedia Entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation).  Hungarian Notation is actually against our teams' coding standards, so I never use it.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer not using any prefix at all for member variables. For those declared outside the method, I use "this.memberVariableName" to distinguish them from those declared inside the method.

Comment: Same, I use it in favor of prefixing with `_`

Answer (score 1):

I tend to go with the first convention, a simple underscore. I also don't specify the type in the name, because I've got Intellisense telling me what it is (I know, it can be a crutch).

Best to check with your coworkers or project teammates and just decide on a convention, some of them are kind of arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ identifiers beginning with _ are considered bad practice, they should be left for internal use. I think this is why prefixing a variable name with _ is sometimes considered bad practice in C# as well... although there is no reason why you can not do it since all of the .NET internals are encapsulated properly, unlike the C/C++ standard libraries.

Comment: In C++ I like the _ as a suffix for member variables (thus avoiding the internal use issue)

Comment: Yeah, that is forbidden by standards. I use 'm' with no underscores - despite conventional wisdom (its easier to read once you get over your perception bias and one less thing to confuse newbies).